# I can't make text direction right to left?

Tags: html, reactjs, text

I'm trying to add the Arabic language to my paragraphs but it appears from left to right. I tried `<HTML lang="ara">` and I tried to do it from `.css` file, but nothing worked with me.

- note I'm using react and I just create the folder without changing anything and the first thing I did is to add the following paragraph.

```
<p lang="ara" dir='rtl' className='title-field' contentEditable />
```

Comment: Can you please also show your CSS?

Answer (score 1):

the html-tag gets the direction-attribute

```html
<html dir="rtl">
  <body>
    <p>aligned right</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can also style specific elements with the direction property:

```
direction: rtl;
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work fine, run the code snippet to see

```html
<p lang="ara" dir='rtl' className='title-field'> نص الاختبار</p>
```